# Скрипт после рендера ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Необходимо вополнить скрипт, когда отрендерится и отобразится на экране некоторый код.

```
ReactDOM.render(<div>72</div>, ...);
console.log('Отобразилось');
```

Нужно, чтобы запись в консоли появилась **после** отображения div'ов на экране. Как такое сделать? Представленный выше код, как я понимаю, работает асинхронно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выделите `<div>72</div>` в отдельную компоненту и используйте `useEffect`

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';

const Component = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
       console.log('Отобразилось');
    }, [])    
    return <div>72</div>;
}
```

И вызовите эту компоненту:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Component />, ...);
```